# += in For loop not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to Python, and hurt to a little issue, here's my code :

```
BitSize = [768, 768]


myCropedTop = 0
for Lenght in BitSize:
    myCropedHeight += Lenght
    left = 0
    top = myCropedTop
    right = width
    bottom = myCropedHeight
    TheBit = Myimage.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
    #increment MyCroped top so the next croped bit start where the previous end
    TheBit.show()
    myCropedTop += Lenght
```

I am used to MaxScript and this is pretty much my first Python script so I have a few questions. Not simple to find an answer for such specific little things.

1. My first `myCropedHeight += Lenght` of my loop isn't working, why ? (the second at the end is so I know it's not a syntax error).
2. As I said I come from a MaxScript background, and in maxscript loops are enclosed into brackets such as :

   ```
   For i in Myexemple do
   (
      Do loop-stuff
   )
   ```

   .. that's certainly a bit stupid to ask that but, how damn do we delimit loops in Python without brackets?

myCropedHeight += Lenght NameError: name 'myCropedHeight' is not defined

this is the error I get with this first += , which is not helping me very much. myCropedHeight = Lenght will be ok...

Comment: Point 2: Statements are grouped entirely by indentation. You did read this in the Python tutorial, right? You really want to keep your posts to **one question** however.

Comment: You forgot to define what *not working* means here; that is **not** a valid problem description.

Comment: Aye, but cannot believe it... it sounds so confusing, no real "visual landmark" such as (). Asked for confirmation there's nothing else.

Comment: myCropedHeight += Lenght
NameError: name 'myCropedHeight' is not defined  = this is the error I get with this first += , which is not helping me very much. myCropedHeight = Lenght will be ok...

Comment: If you really want to argue the point, a whole block of code indented is a much stronger visual indication than some little bracket among all the other symbols.

Comment: @GiantBlob: You need to [edit] your question to add additional detail. Include the *full* traceback.

Comment: I disagree on that point, intended block + brackets (what I am used to) are a much stronger visual indication than indented code alone...

Comment: @GiantBlob well you can always use `from __future__ import braces`

Comment: @GiantBlob: you are on to a sticky wicket there. If you want braces, then perhaps Python is not the language for you.

Comment: I will get used to. It is just very confusing when you are used to something more structured.

Comment: -4 for not putting the little error. That's harsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myCropedHeight` variable is not declared at all, so  `myCropedHeight += Lenght` not working. Value must be declared first, prior to changing value with `+=` (or any other operator).

Code in Python is delimited by indentation, so next line that should not be part of the loop should be aligned in the same line as `for` loop line.

```
for Lenght in BitSize:
    myCropedHeight += Lenght
    left = 0
    top = myCropedTop
    right = width
    bottom = myCropedHeight
    TheBit = Myimage.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
    #increment MyCroped top so the next croped bit start where the previous end
    TheBit.show()
    myCropedTop += Lenght
    #this line here is part of the loop
#this one isn't
```

Comment: He doesn't, but try executing this code and you will see it for yourself. He just says it's not working, which is not very helpful.

Comment: Well apparently he did say he gets a `NameError` in the comments... *sigh*

Comment: If it's just a declaration problem, why myCropedHeight = Lenght would work but myCropedHeight += Lenght won't ?

Comment: Because `Lenght` get the values from `BitSize` sequentially, with every step of the loop, and simple assignment of that value to `myCropedHeight` with `myCropedHeight = Lenght` is not a problem. Problem is when you try to add `Lenght` value to a variable that do not exist. Declare `myCropedHeight = 0` before the loop, and problem solved!

Comment: Ok I see, thanks for the explanation, another MaxScript habit to pay attention I guess.  Thanks for the very quick feedbacks guys.

Comment: Accepting an answer is appreciated :)

Comment: @Reloader, variables are not declared in Python - they are defined.